# Bundle Protocol/Licklider Transmission Protocols needed for TM case in cubesat as per CCSDS standard?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, cubesat

As per CCSDS standard, there is no ARQ mechanism present for Telementry(TM) case. Based on spec it will be taken care by upper layer protocols.

So in this case, can we use simple FTP for Cubesat?
or Bundle protocol/Licklider Transmission Protocol needed?

Kindly clarify.

TIA

[image]

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* There's people here from all kinds of backgrounds, so unexplained acronyms can be baffling to many readers. Can you edit your question and address the following? What is a CCSDS standard? What are ARQs? I think all you need to do is add some links to explanations or definitions. *Thanks!*

Comment: Also, please add a credit (identify the source) of the image. If it's your own work, you can mention that as well. *Thanks!*